# Rewriting a URL - 2 variable without altering current rewrites

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I've got most of the rewrites I need working but I can't get the second part working with 2 variables, here is my code:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ entity.php?vanityName=$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /entity.php?vanityName=$1&section=$2 [L]
```

The last bit needs to allow, for example, http://example.com/vanityName/Section however it doesn't pass the section variable.
How can I fix this while retaining the current rewrites?

How can I get it so it works for /vanityName, /vanityName/section but allows me to keep other directories free of rewriting, like /includes/?

Comment: You are aware the second rule is more specific, and the first one a global rule. Since the global rule (or better said: the more general rule) is put first, your more specific rule is never executed. Conclusion: your htaccess will only run till line 5 and never further.

Comment: Thanks, I really don't know about mod_rewrite, first time I've used it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra rule for every directory you don't want to rewrite:

```
RewriteRule directoryName/? - [L]
```

If you write these rules directly after `RewriteBase /`, no other rules will be checked.